# IntelliJ resolve dependencies of profile

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have a Java project with multiple modules. In this project, one module has a dependency to another one, which is only needed for a specific profile and hence is defined like that:

```xml
<profile>
     <id>myProfile</id>
     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
              <groupId>MyGroupId</groupId>
              <!-- ... -->
         </dependency>
     </dependencies>
     <!-- ... -->
</profile>
```

This works fine when building manually with maven like that:

```sh
mvn clean install -P myProfile
```

When using the IntelliJ build however, the dependency doesn't get resolved.

I've tried the option to *delegate IDE build/run actions to maven*, adding a property for maven in *Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Runner* (namely *-P* -> *myProfile*), and much more which is most likely not of interest.

Is it possible to configure IntelliJ to resolve the dependencies for a specific profile?

Comment: This is really a bad idea to have dependencies via profile...why is such thing needed?

Comment: @khmarbaise because we have multiple customers, whereas one customer requires a special version of a dependency. This was neither my decision, nor am I able to change it.

Comment: Make sure this profile looks activated in IDE, see [Activate Maven profiles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-profiles.html#activate_maven_profiles).

Comment: @Andrey you pointed me into the right direction - it turned out that I could simply deactivate the default profile in the Maven tool window and leave myProfile activated, now it works like a charm! _This_ should be an answer.

Comment: Then make a separate module which contains the dependency and that would solve that problem very simple and will furthermore remove the need to give command line parameters and makes testing in IDE easier...

Answer (score 1):

To help Intellij Idea to understand about your maven profile and maven object mode, you set as default profile in maven so that by default it will be recognized and run by any IDE. I provide below the code snippet.

```
<profile>
    <id>firstProfile</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    ..... Other code goes
  </profile>
```

So inside profile, use this `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>`. It may solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you! However, whilst this does seem to work, I'd prefer not having to change the pom as it's used by my coworkers too and it seems to work in Eclipse.

Comment: @MetaColon, there is one line change in pom.xml ie. <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>. It will work in both Eclipse and Idea.

Comment: If you like the answer, could you please mark it as answered.

Comment: Well to be precise it doesn't answer my question - it's not an IntelliJ configuration. If it turns out that there is no such option, I will of course mark this as an answer, but I'll give other people some more time.

Comment: @MetaColon, Eclipse m2 plugin works in a different way than the Intellij maven. If we make generic change in pom.xml, all the IDEs implementing maven functionality will work. That is why I suggested that one.

Comment: @MetaColon, you can refer below the link. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000133770-How-do-you-control-Maven-Profiles-properly-